# How to use WHERE (SELECT ....)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a pretty complicated reporting function with many conditions, many panels,

I have a record in tbl_my_report

```
id    param_filter

101   FIND_IN_SET(t.owner_department,'0620510200,0621510200,0623510200')
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_abc t WHERE t.id = '1' AND 
      (SELECT mr.param_filter 
       FROM tbl_my_report mr WHERE mr.id = '101'
      )
```

How to use it as a valid condition string?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Seems you are looking for dinamic sql ..  alias buil a part of the query using string. But this is not  allowed  using query result  ... if you want this you should buil the string for query dinamically server side

Comment: You cannot do what you want.  A SQL statement is not arbitrary strings that are munged together; it is a statement in the SQL language.  You need to reconsider your data model.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should normalize your data, and get rid of `FIND_IN_SET`.  So, there should be some department table looking like this:

```
id    | owner
'101' | '0620510200'
'101' | '0621510200'
'101' | '0623510200'
```

With this table in place, you may refactor your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_abc t
WHERE
    t.id = '1' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM department WHERE id = '101' AND owner = t.owner_department);
```

In general, you should avoid storing CSV or other unnormalized data in your database tables, for the very reason that it can make querying difficult.

Comment: Thanks,
but it's much more complicated
record maybe is ..  
FIND_IN_SET(t.owner_department,'0201060100,0201060200') AND !FIND_IN_SET(t.owner_department,'0201060100,0201060300') AND !FIND_IN_SET(t.owner,'@fpt.com.vn') AND FIND_IN_SET(t.requester,'ahmed.shihab@fpt.com.vn')
or longer ,
On my client the are 3 screen levels
MyReport is grandpa
Report is father
and Finally is DetailReport
they are linked by the paths placed on the logs
I need to use the above sentence as a sub param filter on 2nd Screen and 3rd Screen .

Comment: OK, I gave what I think is the best answer given the data you showed us.  As an exercise, see if you can take my answer and extend it to cover two of those calls to `FIND_IN_SET`.  What those calls are really doing is searching for a value in some set.  Well, each `FIND_IN_SET` call should probably be replaced with some kind of join to a table.  I have showed you how to do this for one table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_abc t WHERE  t.id = '1' IN (SELECT mr.param_filter
FROM tbl_my_report mr WHERE mr.id = '101' );
```